# Add header in apache

Tags: apache, header

I have apache and many images on this server. E. g.: `http://test.com/images/abc.jpg`
I want to have possibility do this: if user go to url like this `http://test.com/images/download/abc.jpg` apache must add header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.jpg"`. How I can do it?

Comment: What Apache product do you have? Having Apache means a lot of things, such as Tomcat, James, Geronimo, etc.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a combination of mod_rewrite (to fake the "download" directory) and mod_headers (to add the Content-Disposition header).

Create a .htaccess file in the images directory:

```
<filesmatch ".*">
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=REDIRECT_force_download
</filesmatch>
```

This will set the appropriate header whenever the "REDIRECT_force_download" environment variable is set.

Create a download directory and add this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) ../$1 [L,NC,QSA,E=force_download:1]
```

This will redirect any image requests to the parent (images) directory while adding the "REDIRECT_force_download" environment variable that will trigger the Header command from above.