# Adding the original url as header or query parameter during RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I am looking for a way to get the original URL during RewriteRule and append it to the query string as an additional parameter or add it as a header to the request.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending stuff to the query string is straightforward (just write stuff after a question mark, and don't forget to use the QSA flag to append the original query string); and, well, you can just capture the whole URI and append that:

```
 RewriteRule (.*) test.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

Alternatively, you may try one of the several [server variables](http://www.devhands.com/2008/11/mod_rewrite-server-variables-full-list/) providing info about the request:

```
 RewriteRule .* test.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

Note that the content of server variables may vary wildly between systems.

You can also modifiy headers, but it's not as straightforward. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272738/add-header-in-apache) for a way to do it.

Comment: What if there is a question mark already in the result URL (but i can't know that) - can i write a rewrite rule that handle both cases?

Comment: Yep. Make sure you use the QSA flag, and it'll be fine. [Here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/)'s a rundown on how query string manipulation works.