# get country code from http header and add it to url parameters in apache

Tags: angular, apache, apache2.4

I'm using cloudflare to provide the server with the country code in http header HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY.

I need to get country code from http header and add it to url parameters in apache server using .conf file (virtual host). is that possible?

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

I have an angular dist folder and I'm serving the files using apache server and need the country in the url parameter.

my config file for both php service and angular app(/consultation/*)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hero.azure
    ServerAlias hero.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hero/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "testing"
    AliasMatch ^/consultation(.*) "/var/www/ng2/dist/index.html"
    Alias "/ng2" "/var/www/ng2/dist/ng2/"
    <Directory /var/www/hero/public>
     <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "user"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpass
            Require user user
    </LimitExcept>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is some tries to add the query

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} country
RewriteRule ^/consultation(.*)$ ^/consultation/(.*)?country="%{CF-IPCOUNTRY}i"&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

Comment: try url rewriting concept https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133079/adding-the-original-url-as-header-or-query-parameter-during-rewriterule  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html i do java and i use this its very usefull expressions http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding this rule to the virtual host:

```
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)" COUNTRY=$1
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{ENV:COUNTRY} [A-Z]{2}
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !country [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/consultation(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?country=%{ENV:COUNTRY} [L,QSA,R]
</IfModule>
```